# Create an auto incrementing primary key in DuckDB

Tags: sql, duckdb

Many database engines support auto-incrementing primary keys, and I would like to use this approach in my new DuckDB approach, but I can't figure out how to set it up. For example, in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
);
```

Comment: Did you try google, it seems you have to use sequences because there is no auto increment... https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/create_sequence

Comment: Yes, I came across that page, but can't see how to impement it exactly to fill a primary key column. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: yes :), create a table, then create the sequence. Then while inserting just use "insert into table persons (personid,...) values (nextval('name_of_your_sequence'), ...)"

Comment: see my answer if this is what you wanted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid integer primary key,
    LastName varchar(255) not null,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age integer
);
```

create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_personid START 1;
```

Insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (nextval('seq_personid'), 'Doe', 'John', 99);
```

Comment: You can use the default too, e.g. `Personid integer primary key default nextval('seq_personid')`, which is closer to the auto increment/serial behaviour of PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Yes. For a fuller answer:
Alternatively, try this:

1. Create a sequence:
```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_personid START 1;
```
2. Create a table:
```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('Publisher_Id_Seq'),
    LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(255),
    Age INTEGER
);
```
3. Insert some data:
```sql
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES ('Doe', 'John', 99);
```